# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined discord.js Trying to read array inside json

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

I'm unable to retrieve from my reactions.json the emoji name to match the role.name. Not sure what I'm missing and I've been staring at it for hours. '

A bit confused as to what i'm missing here.

**reactions.json**

```
{
"channel": "test",
"channelID": "",
"roles": {
  "melee": " Melee DPS",
  "ranged": " Ranged DPS",
  "caster": " Caster DPS",
  "healer": " Healer",
  "tank": " Tank"
},
"vote": {
    "melee": "",
    "ranged": "",
    "caster": "",
    "healer": "",
    "beginner": ""
  },
 }
```

**Javascript**

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', addRole);

async function addRole({message, emojis}, user) {

if (message.partial) {
  try {
    await message.fetch();
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching message', err);
    return;
  }
}

const { guild } = message;

const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id);


const reactionsJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('reactions.json', 'utf8'));
const { guild } = message;
const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === reactionsJSON[emojis.name]);

if (!role) {
  console.error(`Role not found for '${reactionsJSON[emojis]}'`);
  return;
}

try {
  member.roles.add(role.id);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error adding role', err);
  return;
}
}
```

Comment: What is flagged as undefined? `role` or `emojis`?

Comment: @TheOtterlord  emojis

Comment: oh, wait a minute. in this code, emojis is not defined?

Comment: @TheOtterlord i'm updating to include the async function. Sorry about that

Comment: ok, so whatever is calling addRole passes through an object that includes message, but that doesn't include emojis (hence it's undefined). So I think the problem lies higher up in the stack?

Comment: oh my you are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I believe that the problem is the deconstruction of the `MessageReaction` property of the event. The object contains message, but not `emojis`, however it contains a value `emoji` which has what you lare looking for.

> .emoji (read only)
>
> - The emoji of this reaction. Either a GuildEmoji object for known custom emojis, or a ReactionEmoji object which has fewer properties. Whatever the prototype of the emoji, it will still have name, id, identifier and toString()

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', addRole);

async function addRole({message, emoji}, user) {

if (message.partial) {
  try {
    await message.fetch();
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching message', err);
    return;
  }
}

const { guild } = message;

const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id);


const reactionsJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('reactions.json', 'utf8'));
const { guild } = message;
const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === reactionsJSON[emoji.name]);

if (!role) {
  console.error(`Role not found for '${reactionsJSON[emoji]}'`);
  return;
}

try {
  member.roles.add(role.id);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error adding role', err);
  return;
}
}
```

[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=emoji)